# Information contained in FFT bins

Tags: math, signal-processing, fft, fftw

I am using the FFTW library for an analysis. Any advice is much appreciated.

Let us assume that we have a function `f[k] = A_k*sin(kwT) + B_k*cost(kwT)` and I want to FFT this with a sampling rate of `N = 4`. Here, `w` is the sidereal frequency of the Earth and `T` is the sidereal time of an event that I am interested in. If I plot the output of the FFT, each bin (4 total) will contain some information. How do I know which bin contains information about a specific `A_k` or `B_k`? Is it true that the first bin of the output, say, corresponds to the information about `A_1` or `B_1` or both?

Comment: It depends on your sampling rate.

Comment: Did you try this with a known waveform to see what coefficients you got? Different implementations of FFT can order things differently - a little bit of research will allow you to solve this yourself. You do seem confused about number of samples, sampling rate, and frequencies. If you only have four samples you hardly need an FFT- you can do it almost in your head.

Answer (score 1):

The `k`-th frequency bin corresponds to a centre-frequency of `k * fs / N`, where `fs` is your sampling frequency, and `N` is your FFT length.

Bear in mind that the "first" bin is at `k == 0`...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are sampling at four times corresponding to 1/4 of the period of the waveform (which has unknown amplitude and phase) and the values observed are a1...a4, then

```
A = (a1-a3)/2;
B = (a2-a4)/2;
```

Give you the cosine and sine amplitudes respectively (if the first sample is at t=0).